# Grails fixture plugin how to load fixtures from an inline plugin?

Tags: grails, fixtures, fixture

we have an application that uses a centralized domain using an inline plugin. We where using bootstrap data so all of our applications that use the domain could use the bootstrap. Now when using the Fixture plugin we run into the problem that it wants to read the fixture files from a location inside application instead of the shared inline plugin. All .load() methods look for a fixture file inside the application.

Is there a way of loading the fixture files from a central place instead of the fixture directory inside the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this is not possible.
See Grails Jira issues:
http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPFIXTURES-16

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem so I created a config value that allows you to set a config value.

This commit should do the trick, but it's not merged into the plugin (yet):
https://github.com/nwittstruck/grails-fixtures/commit/1cea0da7bf32303885cc536fe89bb9be483375bc